# How to programatically tell Spring Boot application that application.yml is in app user home directory?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy, configuration

I am attempting to move my `application.yml` outside of my application to the user directory that the application runs under.  I am aware that a common approach is to use startup params at runtime like `-Dconfig.location=/path/to/external.properties` (which incidentally I can't seem to make work propertly), but I need to be able to do this without changing the startup script if at all possible.

My goal was to do this in the `main()` method of the application groovy file that starts the app.  In that method, I am detecting the user's home directory, and am attempting to set that as a property for the app to use.  However, all approaches I have attempted have ended up with a FileNotFound (`application.yml`).  can someone offer any advice on achieving what I want?  Below is the most recent attempt

```
static void main(String[] args)  throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, URISyntaxException  {
    String configPath = "${System.getProperty('user.home')}"
    ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext = new SpringApplicationBuilder(Angular4SpringbootApplication)
            .properties("spring.config.name:application,conf",
            "spring.config.location=classpath:$configPath/application.yml")
            .build().run(args)

    SpringApplication.run(Angular4SpringbootApplication, args)
}
```

Comment: Your user home dir isn't part of the class path, hence `classpath:` will not work. Instead use `file:`. Also instead of `spring.config.location` I suggest to use `spring.config.additional-location` instead. This will leave the defaults and simply add this one (see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files).

Answer (score 0):

> If you do not like application.properties as the configuration file
>   name, you can switch to another file name by specifying a
>   spring.config.name environment property. You can also refer to an
>   explicit location by using the spring.config.location environment
>   property (which is a comma-separated list of directory locations or
>   file paths). The following example shows how to specify a different
>   file name:

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject
```

Or you can use location (if rour file is outside your app, prefix with `file:` ) :

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/default.properties
```

> spring.config.name and spring.config.location are used very early to
>   determine which files have to be loaded, so they must be defined as an
>   environment property (typically an OS environment variable, a system
>   property, or a command-line argument).

### Edit

If you want to do it without changing the startup script, you can do it like this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SimpleBoot {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("spring.config.location","file:/path/to/application.yml")
        SpringApplication.run(SimpleBoot.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you actually read what I said?  Specifically: " I need to be able to do this without changing the startup script if at all possible. My goal was to do this in the main() method of the application groovy file that starts the app".    What you have shown me is changing the startup parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Since you pass the command line parameters to `SpringApplication.run` you could simply modify them before. I don't know much about Groovy, but I think this should work:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Angular4SpringbootApplication, ["--spring.config.location=file:${System.getProperty('user.home')}/application.yml"] + args)
}
```

You could also set a system property before starting the Spring context:

```
static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty('spring.config.location', "${System.getProperty('user.home')}/application.yml")
    SpringApplication.run(Angular4SpringbootApplication, args)
}
```